# JavaScript Windows automatically minimizing

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, functional-programming, popupwindow

My JavaScript Windows keeps on automatically minimizing itself. It briefly pops up and then minimizes.

Here is my code:

```
function ESRlink9()
{   
   if (esr_link.value == "9" && seen_message.value != "True" && last_updated.value < "2015-01-01 00:00:00.000")
     {
      window.open('alerts/alert.html','StatusBar', 'toolbar=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,width=520,height=420,left=500,top=200' )
      UpdateSeenMessage('True')
      }
   else
     {
     alert("Your details are fine")
     }

     }
function UpdateSeenMessage(update_text2)
     {
     getDoc('/sorce/configs/enh_ui/banner/updateSeenMessage.aspx?update_text2=' + update_text2)
     }
```

Could you take a look and share your thoughts please?

Comment: It has probably something to do with your `UpdateSeenMessage('True')`. Some additional code would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, have added in the UpdateSeenMessage function too.